# PHP Item Tweeter

Tags: php

See Im making something that will tweet an item from just a click of a button.
Heres the snippet of the Item part:

```
    $arr = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json"),true);
$elements = array_slice($arr, $page * $elementsPerPage, $elementsPerPage);
foreach($elements as $item)
{
$label = $item['label'];
$id = $item['paper_item_id'];
}
$cpitems = array("Check out the $label at http://www.cpcheatsdojo.info/SWFViewer/items.swf?id=$id [$random]");
```

So thats the snippet. The Problem is when i click the button it tweets out the same item. Im trying to make tweet random items.

Comment: Where do you randomize your results? What are your results? And what do you "tweet" eventually?

Comment: what's the point of the foreach? you simply overwrite $label/$id with each item in the array, and end up with the LAST pair in the array. each time.

Comment: Marc B, so should I take out my foreach?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) which allows you to:

> Pick one or more random entries out of an array

The code:

```
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://media1.clubpenguin.com/play/en/web_service/game_configs/paper_items.json"),true);
$elements = array_slice($arr, $page * $elementsPerPage, $elementsPerPage);

$items = array_rand($elements, 1);
$item = $elements[$items[0]];
$label = $item['label'];
$id = $item['paper_item_id'];
```

Comment: It will just tweet: Check out the at http://www.cpcheatsdojo.info/SWFViewer/items.swf?id= Which is not what I wanted

Comment: If you do `var_dump($item)` at the end, what does it show you?

Comment: How is it the same thing? I asked you to add `var_dump($item)` to the end. This should tell you what values the array contains for debugging...

Comment: @TimmyCP1505 did you manage to get it working? Do you need me to help with anything else?